# Indicate how full review queues are within the top bar dropdown

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, new-nav, top-bar

When clicking the "Review Queues" icon in the top bar, one can see the sizes of each queue, but not how close to the queue limit it is.

This information would be useful, however, because a queue being full degrades the operation of the site. For example, suggested edits are disabled altogether when [the number of pending edits is 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398). So it would help in my opinion if we showed this, and the users knew where to concentrate their effort.

A mockup of the dialog could look like this:

[image]

This is how the drop down looks now:

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: The suggested edits queue is the only one with a capacity, so it's not a sensible operation for any of the other queues.

Comment: @Servy: How certain are you about that? I think I read somewhere about other queues (triage perhaps?) not being fed with new items after a specific size. Looking for the link now...

Comment: Different queues will behave differently in different ways based on their size.  Triage for example will affect what types of items get triaged based on the size, but there isn't a hard capacity in any of the other cases.  In the case of triage questions flagged as VLQ will go to the queue, regardless of its size.

Comment: Just highlight Suggested Edits and put "full" in red text between the name and the number.